# Elasticsearch group, filter and aggregation in the same request

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a use case to filter and group by two separate fields in Elasticsearch, while aggregating values in rest of the fields. Looking for help formulating a query for Elasticsearch. Here is an example. Each document has a `locationId`, `category`, `productId`, `visitCount`, `purchaseCount` and `sampleCount`. I want to view sums of `visitCount`, `purchaseCount` and `sampleCount` for each category within each location. Note that `productId` is unique across all entries. I have tried reading up Elasticsearch documentation but could not find a good source to learn how I can do grouping, filtering and aggregation all together. Please note that this is for a website use case where we show this data in a table with pages. Due to the amount of locations and categories, it is likely that there will be several groups that will go beyond 1 page. Please help formulate a query for Elasticsearch.

Sample documents:

```
[{
    "locationId": 12345,
    "category": "Food",
    "productId": "JKHNG98",
    "visitCount": 10,
    "purchaseCount": 9,
    "sampleCount": 7
}, {
    "locationId": 12345,
    "category": "Food",
    "productId": "HJUSY68",
    "visitCount": 1,
    "purchaseCount": 15,
    "sampleCount": 7
}, {
    "locationId": 12345,
    "category": "Entertainment",
    "productId": "KGUJKHG78",
    "visitCount": 20,
    "purchaseCount": 15,
    "sampleCount": 10
}, {
    "locationId": 12345,
    "category": "Entertainment",
    "productId": "67912HYK",
    "visitCount": 5,
    "purchaseCount": 15,
    "sampleCount": 10
}, {
    "locationId": 54321,
    "category": "Food",
    "productId": "9823HYKN",
    "visitCount": 15,
    "purchaseCount": 12,
    "sampleCount": 5
}, {
    "locationId": 54321,
    "category": "Food",
    "productId": "KJHKJSAHD22",
    "visitCount": 55,
    "purchaseCount": 12,
    "sampleCount": 5
}, {
    "locationId": 54321,
    "category": "Entertainment",
    "productId": "SDJFHSF788",
    "visitCount": 45,
    "purchaseCount": 44,
    "sampleCount": 23
}, {
    "locationId": 54321,
    "category": "Entertainment",
    "productId": "2131286JH",
    "visitCount": 80,
    "purchaseCount": 44,
    "sampleCount": 23
}]
```

Input can be multiple location IDs but always just 1 category.

Expected result for filter input category "Food":

```
[{
    "locationId": 12345,
    "category": "Food",
    "sumOfVisitCount": 11,
    "sumOfPurchaseCount": 24,
    "sumOfSampleCount": 14
},{
    "locationId": 54321,
    "category": "Food",
    "sumOfVisitCount": 15,
    "sumOfPurchaseCount": 12,
    "sumOfSampleCount": 5
}]
```

Expected result for filter input of location "12345":

```
[{
    "locationId": 12345,
    "category": "Food",
    "sumOfVisitCount": 11,
    "sumOfPurchaseCount": 24,
    "sumOfSampleCount": 14
}, {
    "locationId": 12345,
    "category": "Entertainment"
    "sumOfVisitCount": 25,
    "sumOfPurchaseCount": 30,
    "sumOfSampleCount": 20
}]
```

Expected result for filter input of location "12345" and category "Food":

```
[{
    "locationId": 12345,
    "category": "Food",
    "sumOfVisitCount": 11,
    "sumOfPurchaseCount": 24,
    "sumOfSampleCount": 14
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of query and aggregation to achieve your required result. Below query uses :

**Search Query for filter input category "Food"**

1. Query part uses [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) to match the documents that have category equal to Food
2. [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) is used, to create buckets based on `locationId`, and in order to find the sum of `sampleCount`, `viewCount` and `purchaseCount`, [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) is used

```
POST idxtest/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "category.keyword": "Food"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "locationId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sumOfPurchaseCount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "purchaseCount"
          }
        },
        "sumOfVisitCount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "visitCount"
          }
        },
        "sumOfSampleCount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "sampleCount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 12345,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "sumOfSampleCount" : {
            "value" : 14.0
          },
          "sumOfVisitCount" : {
            "value" : 11.0
          },
          "sumOfPurchaseCount" : {
            "value" : 24.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 54321,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "sumOfSampleCount" : {
            "value" : 10.0
          },
          "sumOfVisitCount" : {
            "value" : 70.0
          },
          "sumOfPurchaseCount" : {
            "value" : 24.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Search Query for filter input of location "12345" and category "Food"**

```
POST idxtest/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category.keyword": "Food"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "locationId": 12345
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "locationId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sumOfPurchaseCount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "purchaseCount"
          }
        },
        "sumOfVisitCount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "visitCount"
          }
        },
        "sumOfSampleCount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "sampleCount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result :**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 12345,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "sumOfSampleCount" : {
            "value" : 14.0
          },
          "sumOfVisitCount" : {
            "value" : 11.0
          },
          "sumOfPurchaseCount" : {
            "value" : 24.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Rishab its been quite some time now. Did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you ;-)

Comment: @Rishab if the answer helped you resolve your issue, then please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer! TIA ;-)